# What are these '{' and '}' characters called?

Tags: ascii

I was just trying to explain programming in JavaScript to a friend of mine who is just starting out with programming and I called the `'{'` and `'}'` characters *curly braces* (or brackets). He laughed at me and said surely they have a better name than that and I realized that I don't know if they do.

Do they have a formal name?

Comment: `curly braces` or `curly brackets` will be just fine!

Comment: I would call `{}` "braces", `()` "parentheses", `[]` "square brackets" and `<>` "angle brackets".

Comment: A better one is the technical name for `#`: octothorpe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, they are simply known as Braces:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Braces_or_Curly_brackets_.7B_.7D

Comment: Would not have said it better.

Comment: @JustinNiessner, +1 for the link. I did a google search but my google-fu wasn't as good as yours.

Comment: If you are in England, in the US they are curly brackets.  Wooooop Wooooop Wooooop

Answer (score 1):

THe formal name is curly brackets, but they have many pet names such as curly braces, flower brackets, etc...

Yes, curly brackets is the formal name...

Comment: The Unicode names are also "left curly bracket" and "right curly bracket".