# Is there a proper term for "curly braces" among programmers - { }

Tags: terminology, curly-braces

`{ }`

I'm wondering if there is a more professional term other than "Curly Brace" that is used by programmers.

A google search said they are also referred to as "brackets", but in my experience when people say brackets they mean the square "[ ]".

Comment: The Unicode names are "left curly bracket" and "right curly bracket".

Comment: The word is braces, `[` is a bracket.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Curly_brackets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are these '{' and '}' characters called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981322/what-are-these-and-characters-called)

Comment: thanks for the responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use whatever floats your boat, in most contexts; on account of regional flavours. If you feel extra formal, you might be using "curly bracket" instead.

Wikipedia shows many variations on names for the `{ }` symbols. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Names_for_various_bracket_symbols

You could also imply them, sometimes, by talking about **blocks**, **loops**, **switch block**, **if block**, and other similar structures if the programming language in question features them. Programmers will just visualize the brackets as being present, as necessary:

> The *else-block* is never executed because X.

Another way: imply the type by its relative position/usage. If the context is right, it'll be a curly bracket.

> You're missing a *closing bracket* for the *while-loop*, that's why the compiler failed.

Answer (score 2):

As a working mathematician in publishing I find it best to call {} braces, [] brackets and () parens (or parentheses). We call <> angle brackets and || are abs or absolute brackets. All that matters is that printers get your meaning without wasting time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are searching for the term `scope` because **usually** in programming languages like Java, C#, Js etc the `Curly Brace` defines a scope

Comment: I thought about the term closure as I was writing the post but thought it was too specific to javascript. From the comments above it sounds like curly brace is proper. It just sounds a bit like slang to me. Thanks for the response. Scope is a good term to keep in mind when referring to curly braces in code.